# How to get label from apify scrapers: Web, Cheerio, and Puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer, cheerio, apify

When I try to get the label of the Start URL based on the examples on the Apify web site, I get an error of `2019-12-26T15:35:17.723Z INFO: request.userData.label: undefined`.

The Cheerio scraper [example code](https://docs.apify.com/scraping/cheerio-scraper):

```
async function pageFunction(context) {
    const { request, log, skipLinks, $ } = context;
    log.info(`request.userData.label ${request.userData.label}`);
}
```

The Pupperrer scraper [example code](https://docs.apify.com/scraping/puppeteer-scraper):

```
async function pageFunction(context) {
    const { request, log, skipLinks, page } = context;
     log.info(`request.userData.label ${request.userData.label}`);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in the [Introduction section](https://docs.apify.com/scraping/introduction). You need to set labels for Start and Pseudo URLs.